# Copy files except some directories

Tags: centos

I want to backup files inside "var/www/html" of my server before modifying anything.
this is what i tried:

```
ssh root@172.16.4.25 "mkdir /var/www/html/backup_$BUILD_ID"

ssh root@172.16.4.25 "mv !(backup_$BUILD_ID) /var/www/html/* /var/www/html/backup_$BUILD_ID "
```

I tried mv !(folder_name), cp -r !(folder name),rsync -aP --exclude=backup nothign worked as expected.
The final goal is to backup all files under html inside backup_$BUILD_ID except for folders starting with "backup".

Comment: (1) [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). A simple solution is to have backups *outside* of the directory being backed up. Alternatively in a hidden directory (e.g. `/var/www/html/.backup/`), so `/var/www/html/*` won't match it. (2) Assuming you cannot improve the directory structure, shell globs are a decent idea, but your `!` does not look like anything `mv` or the shell could understand as exclusion. There are ways to exclude from globs, they depend on the shell. What is the shell on the remote side? (3) `mv` is hardly ever a backup. Why was it your first choice?.

Comment: i'll consider doing a backup outside of the directory being backed up to avoid problems.First time i think about backup in linux so the first things that came to my mind are cp and mw

Comment: My point is `cp` is OK as it makes a *copy*. `mv` moves data, this is not a backup because the original data does not remain.

Comment: ah i got it.I'm using mv because the files are going to be modified with a cron job just after my backup